# Adding two numbers in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Addition</title>
    <script>
        function display(id_name,result_name){
       document.getElementById(result_name).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id_name).value;
       }
       function calculate(id1,id2,result_id) {
       document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById(id1).value)+parseInt(document.getElementById(id2).value)
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input">
    Enter 1st Number:
    <input type="text" id="input1_text">
    <button type="button" onclick="display('input1_text','input1')">Enter 1st Number</button>
    <span id="input1"></span>
</div>

<div class="input">
    Enter 2nd Number:
    <input type="text" id="input2_text">
    <button type="button" onclick="display('input2_text','input2')">Enter 2nd Number</button>
    <span id="input2"></span>
</div>
<div class="result">
    <button type="button" onclick="calculate('input1_text','input2_text','result_value')">Calculate</button>
    <span id="result_value"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so in the above code i am not only adding 2 nubmers but also displaying the numbers after pressing the button.so now what i am looking for is to make this using flask framework on pressing buttons their respective functions should be fired up and data should be updated.I have tried using forms so the problem is on clicking button of 1st number to display is whole page is refreshing and i am losing whole data.so now how do i write those functions in python and also making   sure that the page should not reload.Also is it possible to reuse the display function based on the paramters rather than hard coding and writing 2 display functions for 2 numbers seperately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you need to use the user inputted values in the backend of your application, you can simply perform the calculations in the front-end:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <p>Input first number:</p>
   <input type='text' class='first_val'>
   <p>Input second number:</p>
   <input type='text' class='second_val'>
   <div class='results'></div>
   <button type='button' class='calculate'>Calculate</button>
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.calculate').click(function() {
       var val1 = parseInt($('.first_val').val());
       var val2 = parseInt($('.second_val').val());
       var val3 = val1+val2;
       $('.results').html('The result is '+val3);
     });
   });
 </script>
</html>
```

Edit: using Python in the backend, `ajax` can be utilized:

`index.html`:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <p>Input first number:</p>
   <input type='text' class='first_val'>
   <p>Input second number:</p>
   <input type='text' class='second_val'>
   <div class='results'></div>
   <button type='button' class='calculate'>Calculate</button>
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.calculate').click(function() {
       var val1 = $('.first_val').val();
       var val2 = $('.second_val').val();
       $.ajax({
        url: "/get_numbers",
        type: "get",
        data: {val1: val1, val2:val2},
        success: function(response) {
            $(".results").html(response.packet);
         },
          error: function(xhr) {
          //Do Something to handle error
         }
        });
     });
   });
 </script>
</html>
```

Then, in the Python app:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
   return flask.render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get_numbers')
def get_values():
   value1 = flask.request.args.get('val1')
   value2 = flask.request.args.get('val2')
   return flask.jsonify({'data':f'<p>The result is: {value1+value2}</p>'})
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but what i am looking for is to do this job using a python function like maybe using forms and getting the details of the input field from request.forms but problem is how to display back the whole content on button click.Like we even need to display the number after button is clicked in above example display function is doing the job for us.so is it possible to do this job in flask or use some other frame like django or anyother

Comment: Thanks for your time but you forgot the display function where after entering the number into the text field the user clicks the button and the text in the input changes to empty and the text is placed into a field but that is not the problem i already solved this problem in other way round but its a bit lengthy and so much dupilicate code.I dont want to post it here though maybe we can connect in pythontutor at sometime

Comment: @Rockstar The edit I added uses `ajax` to perform exactly the operation you have described.

Comment: @Rockstar What specifically is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should build an flask API function: a GET route which accepts the argument from your form and returns a JSON response object.

Then in your HTML when you click the button that should perform an AJAX GET quesry accessing your API route and return the values to that page. This avoids having Flask re-render your page and returns the data directly to your existing client web browser.

To make it easy to manipulate data dynamically in the webpage I suggest a JS framework like angular, react or vue. Personally I prefer vue since it can be self contained, loaded as script into the page and the setup is often minimal. The docs are also very easy and you can easily see how to link form input controls.